# Filtering Results with JQuery.grep in PHP from Json Txt File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, grep

I'm able to pull my JSON results into my table with no problem, but when it comes to filtering the results based on my PHP `$_GET` variables I can't seem to return a result set.

My table is simple:

```
<table id="displaythatdata">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Meter</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>that</td>
      <td>that2</td>
      <td>that3</td>
      <td>that4</td>
      <td>that5</td>
      <td>that6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery function looks like this. I am simply trying to append my table with the results from the `$_GET` variables I set using PHP:

```
Json_return = [];

jQuery(function(){
  jQuery.getJSON('./json/acm2.txt',{},function(data){

    Json_return = data;
    jQuery('#displaythatdata').eq(0).html('');
    jQuery(Json_return).each(function(indx,Val){

      var returnedData = $.grep(Json_return, function(element, index){

        return element.PLAT = <?php echo $getthedivision ?>;
        return element.DIVISION  = <?php echo $getthedivision ?>;


        jQuery('#displaythatdata').eq(0).append('<tr>
                <td>'+returnedData.METER+'</td><td>'+returnedData.LOCADDRESS+'</td>
                <td>'+returnedData.CITY+'</td><td>'+returnedData.INSPECTION_DATETIME+'</td>
                <td>'+returnedData.INSPECTION_STATUS+'</td><td>'+returnedData.LOC+'</td>
                </tr>');
      });
    });
  });
```

My PHP is standard:

```
$getthedivision = $_GET['getregion'];
$gettheplat = $_GET['getplat'];
```

My JSON looks like:

```
[{"ID":1,"UUID":"5D2F830-8757-F80FA715A78E","SPID":86810,"METER":"900A","LOCADDRESS":"123 MEADOW RD","CITY":"SANTA ANA","DIVISION":"SAN DIEGO","PLAT":"1145-C08","ADDRESS_NUM":123,"ADDRESS_EVODD":1,"ADDRESS_STREET":"MEADOW RD","GRD_BELOW_SU":null,"GRD_ABOVE_SU":null,"MANIFOLD_METER":null"},
```

Any ideas on why I can return a result set based on my PHP `$_GET` variables? I am able to print them out so I know they are being set. I saw that `.grep()` was the way to filter using jQuery JSON. Is this the case for objects too?

Comment: Do you want to look through each piece of the JSON object and get the one where region and plat are something specific?

Comment: My goal is to Filter using my $_GET variables... I need All fields returned but sorted according to what the $_GET vars are set with.

Comment: It should sort it in that array.